# Docker process repeatedly restarting itself when I don't want it to

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I recently created a Docker registry. Subsequently I noticed that in addition to the registry I created, a new registry with a similar name to this is being created:

```
registry.1.y6qfm3eu37ampm4qsbonr3wd4
```

The start, `registry.1`, is always the same. The sequence after appears random.

Initially, the container was listed by Docker as using the image registry:2. I deleted the container and the registry:2 image. A short time after the container was again listed, with an image that was instead given the name of what looks like a short SHA, similar to this:

```
728bc6af7e5e
```

After a short time longer, upon deletion this strange new registry container began to again recreate itself with the image again listed as registry:2 instead of the number which I assume to be a short SHA. `Docker images` shows no images titled `registry:2`, but only `registry`, `docker`, and my letsencrypt image.

The original registry I have deleted and would like to start afresh.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that a docker service was recreating the container. I found the Docker service and ran `Docker service rm registry`. I now have a clean base to start from as I wanted.